# How to choose and equip armor in Suikoden

Tags: suikoden

What's the best way to choose and equip armor in Suikoden, and how do I know if a character can wear a specific armor?

I just bought a karate Uniform for Tai Ho in Kouan. His name was green in the store when I bought it. However when I go to his equipment view, the new item doesn't appear as an option to equip. The same happened with Leather Armor for Gremio and Viktor. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Is there some message that you can't equip?  "for some reason" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: @joedragons good point! I've updated the question with more detail

Comment: When you bought it, did you give it to the character in question or someone else?  IIRC (and from youtube video) you only equip stuff in your inventory.  So if you bought leather armor for Gremio and gave it to someone else, I don't think you'd see it.  (in other words, suggest you check your inventory and make sure it's there)